# "Open with" Default value inside flatpak application

Tags: pdf, flatpak, mendeley

I've just downloaded Mendeley app from flathub (installed through the Software Center) and it is working great. However, everytime I try to open a PDF inside the app using an external viewer, it prompts me an `Open with...` dialog where I select Document Viewer. However, this election doesn't get saved and so, each time I open a PDF inside my flatpak'ed Mendeley, I must select the PDF Viewer.

I think that the dialog prompt is the way flatpak is supposed to work. Due to sandboxing, applications can't know my system-wide preferences. However, is there a way to save the per-flatpak application preferences? In the web some people mentioned the dialog should have a "Select as default application" kind of dialog however, in my system, that option is nowhere to be found.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the latest updates from the official stable repository.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution I've found is to use `xdg-desktop-portal` v1.5.3 or later.

After a bit of digging in the `xdg-desktop-portal` repository I've found this [commit](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/commit/53ef3361c1b513bbe092d0fc3b71f39c90dde2b4). Basically it introduces a threshold value. After choosing the same app three times it will set it as the default. It's further refined to be less obtrusive in v1.5.4. Check out the release notes of [v1.5.3](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/releases/tag/1.5.3) and [v1.5.4](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/releases/tag/1.5.4). Not tested personally as I am using the default version supplied with Fedora which is currently behind upstream.